# Fanuc_driver_exp for robot with roboguide V9.10

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to run the fanuc_driver_exp on R30i-B plus controller with Roboguide 9.10, but have no luck with it.
I got the fanuc_driver working on the R30i-B plus, by loading the .kl and .ls files Roboguide and compiling the code there (see the [link](http://wiki.ros.org/fanuc/Tutorials/hydro/Installation) for the steps i took).

There are some limits in the fanuc_drive so i wanted too install the fanuc_driver_exp.
I followed the steps on the [git](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/fanuc_driver_exp) and source build the files.
Wen i try to copy it on the Fanuc controller (via the  teach pendant) i got the message:

> Program version is too old

Than i tried to load the .kl and .ls files and compile it like the fanuc_driver instruction, but i could not build it in roboguide.

Can anyone help me to get the fanuc_driver_exp for Robotguide 9.10?

I run ROS kinetic on a ubuntu 16.04 system and run Roboguide on a windows 10 system.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320133/fanuc_driver_exp-for-robot-with-roboguide-v9.10/) by [Kluun](https://answers.ros.org/users/37797/kluun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I followed the steps on the [git](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/fanuc_driver_exp) and source build the files.

One of the settings to configure when invoking `rossum` is the "core version" (ie: the base system software version), using the `-c` or `--core` flag:

```
  -c ID, --core ID      Version of the core files used when translating
                        (default: V7.70-1). Use the 'ROSSUM_CORE_VERSION'
                        environment variable to configure an alternative
                        default without having to specify it on each
                        invocation of rossum
```

as stated there, the default is to use `V7.70-1`. For your R-30iB+, that would probably need to be set to `V9.10-1`.

Could you check you did that?

You can find the currently configured core version in the `build.ninja` file in the `build` folder of your `rossum` workspace (look for the `/ver` argument to `ktransw.cmd` near the top of the file (under *build rules*).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-02**:
And of course please make sure you actually need to build from source. There are binary distributions available in the [release section](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/fanuc_driver_exp/releases) of the repository.

**Comment by [Kluun](https://answers.ros.org/users/37797/kluun/) on 2019-04-02**:
Thx @gvdhoorn. I changed the /ver number into the build.ninja file and it successfully installed on the controller

**Comment by [qwrtyuiop](https://answers.ros.org/users/40721/qwrtyuiop/) on 2019-04-03**:
@Kluun I'm trying to use this driver with my 9.10 version system as well, but unfortunately I do not have a copy of Roboguide. Is it possible for you to provide the files that you made?

**Comment by [Kluun](https://answers.ros.org/users/37797/kluun/) on 2019-04-09**:
@qwrtyuiop if you give me a email address i can send you the Karel files.

**Comment by [nicob](https://answers.ros.org/users/85320/nicob/) on 2022-04-04**:
Now, I run into the same trouble. It is not possible for my to compile the driver for controller version 9.10-1 by myself due to our company IT restrictions. I get all the time the msg ninja has no access.

So, is there a compiled package out there, now?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-04-04**:\

> due to our company IT restrictions. I get all the time the msg ninja has no access.

all of the used tools are run from user-writable directories. No special permissions are needed. If you have Roboguide installed, the rest is all run from a sub directory of your user's home directory (ie: `%USERPROFILE%` on Windows). If you don't have access there, something else is wrong.

**Comment by [nicob](https://answers.ros.org/users/85320/nicob/) on 2022-04-05**:
I think it is not a problem with write permissions in the directories. Rossum works perfectly with absolut path specifications to ktransw.cmd, ktrans.exe, etc. It writes also the `build.ninja` w/o problems.

Unfortunaly I can not provoke more information with the flag `-v`.

I get the info in various stackoverflow threads, that this problem of ninja is often caused by Windows Defender. And it is not possible for me to deactivate or modify ist. Our company IT support ist not really helpfull to special requests.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-04-05**:
Ninja sometimes gets flagged due to a false positive in Windows Defender. That's a problem with a Microsoft product.

Working around that doesn't sound like a special request, but I understand IT departments can be difficult with things that don't align with their typical day-to-day operations.

I'll see if I can build the files for you, but I cannot give you an ETA on when that would be. Perhaps finding a non-corporate laptop/PC with Windows would be faster.

**Comment by [nicob](https://answers.ros.org/users/85320/nicob/) on 2022-04-05**:
Thanks, this would be great! I send you an e-mail with my contact information to your CoR adress.

The main problem is, I am something like a lone wolf in my company working on the automation topics. So, the IT department has some trouble to follow my works. Its a structural problem and I am still working on it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-04-05**:
I've uploaded binaries for an interim release, which includes binaries for `V9.10`. See [fanuc_driver_exp/releases](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/fanuc_driver_exp/releases).

**Comment by [nicob](https://answers.ros.org/users/85320/nicob/) on 2022-04-07**:
Thank you! The driver works fine for me.